# Load database into Bootstrap modal

Tags: ajax, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I have an employee database from which I load employee images into a bootstrap grid. On the initial page load, I display all employees, and then I click on various buttons to change the views depending on the query.

What I'm stuck on mow is the bootstrap modal that I want to implement.

I currently have the modal appearing with an image and other information like name, work location, etc. However, the modal will only display the first image (and associated information), regardless of which image I click from the main page. My assumption is that I have to do an ajax call to reload data for the modal when I click on an image. I would do a MySQL query to select * from the database where the file = $imageURL.

I've read numerous posts, and this one seems to be what I'm looking for, although I cannot seem to figure it out: [bootstrap modal does not load new data from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49290412/bootstrap-modal-does-not-load-new-data-from-database)

This is the code I am currently working from: I've almost got everything working, except for this last part. Any help is appreciated! Thanks

```
<?php
 include ('db_connect.php');

 $sql = "SELECT * from monctonfir where 1 ";

 if(isset($_GET['specialty'])) $sql .= " AND specialty = '".$_GET['specialty']."' ";
 $sql .=" order by initials ASC";
 $result = $db->query($sql);

 if($result->num_rows > 0){
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $imageURL = 'image/'.$row["file"];
        $initial = $row["initials"];
        $name = $row["name"];
        $location = $row["location"];

    ?>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Employee Profile</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria- 
label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <img src="<?php echo "$imageURL" ?>"/>
        <p style="text-align: right">Name: <?php echo $name ?></p>
        <p style="text-align: right">Location: <?php echo $location ?></p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

    <!-- End Modal-->   
    <div id="photos" class = "col-lg-1 no-gutters" style="margin-top:1rem;">
    <div class="card" style="width: 6.5rem;">
    <a href = "#">
        <img id="staff" type="button" class="img card-img-top" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" src = "<?php echo $imageURL ?>"> 
    </a>
    <div class = "card-body">
        <h5 class = "card-title round-button" style="text-align: center;"><?php echo $initial  ?></h5>
    </div>

    </div>
    </div>


    <?php }
 } ?>
```

Comment: You are repeating your modal code inside the while loop, if you want the modal to refresh with new data you only need 1 modal box, not 1 for every user (although this is possible). The problem comes down to not having unique IDs

Comment: Thanks - I'm not following though. I thought the modal is in the right place so I have access to the php variables. I actually only want one modal. If I click on my image, I want the modal to show my image, name, location. If I click on another persons image, I want the modal to display their image, name, location. Can you elaborate a little more?

Comment: You don't need the php variables for the modal yet, you need to make an AJAX call to a PHP file that returns those variables for you to fill in the modal. Your modal should be outside the while loop. You also need to make sure when you are creating your html, all elements have a unique ID, if you take your modal out of the while loop you still have repeating IDs which will cause errors later on for you - <div id="photos", <img id="staff" etc.

Comment: Ideally you should have an ID column in your DB that allows you to reference each specific row and can be used to set IDs for html elements that reference that particular row.

Comment: Understood - that's the problem. I assumed i needed a new AJAX call but I don't understand how that is supposed to work. Is the AJAX a POST or GET? Do I write my sql query in the PHP file? I do have an AI id field in the database. Thanks so much for your help so far - appreciate it

Comment: It's normally easier to create a new PHP file for ajax calls and to return your results in JSON. Yes you would write your SQL query for retrieving users info in that file. All you would need to send is the ID and retrieve that specific row and the required columns to populate the modal fields.

Comment: You can use POST or GET that is up to you but generally speaking you should use POST.

Comment: Thanks - I'll keep researching to try and figure it out. Your help was great!